# Watin unable to cast object as specific type

Tags: watin

I'm trying to inspect a td. I'm pulling the object out of the dom using:

```
string tdSelector = "#myTD";
TableCell td = ie.Element(Find.BySelector(tdSelector)) as TableCell;
```

This returns null because of the cast. So the following code

```
Element elm = ie.Element(Find.BySelector(tdSelector));
```

works just fine.

Further more elm.TagName returns "TD"

```
TableCell td = (TableCell)ie.Element(Find.BySelector(tdSelector));
```

throws an error: **Unable to cast object of type 'WatiN.Core.ElementContainer`1[WatiN.Core.Element]' to type 'WatiN.Core.TableCell'.**

So the object is there, I can get to it, but I cannot treat it as a TableCell object. I see there is a method .As<> so I tried .As<TableCell>() which also does not work.

Any ideas? My goal is to get a TableCell object.

Answer (score 3):

I was curious about this as well, and I've finally found a way. You can't cast `Element` to a class specific to an HTML tag, however you can create a brand new `TableCell` and use the `Element` to construct it.

```
Element element = ie.Element("someId");
TableCell cell = new TableCell(element.DomContainer, element.NativeElement);
```

This doesn't appear to throw an exception if the `Element` is not *actually* a table cell.

Comment: After doing this, if you edit the cell object will the change be reflected on the page?

Comment: I did check. Try it out :)

Answer (score 0):

So far as I can tell this is not possible without really mangling the framework. Out of the box it was not designed to do this (so far as I can tell). Ideally get the object you want out instead of trying to cast it.

```
 ie.TableCell(Find.BySelector(tdSelector))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the table cells of a table in the following way:

```
    foreach (TableRow tr in details.TableRows)
    {
        TableCellCollection tcs = tr.TableCells;
        for (int b = 0; b < tcs.Count; b++)
        {
             // each cell for each row and search whatever you need in here.
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: At the heart of the question is how to convert an Element into another type of object such as a TableCell. I believe this to be impossible.